# perl how to extract #define'd number from C header file

Tags: c, regex, perl, c-preprocessor

I am looking for a Perl snippet to print the number `100`, contained in a C header, to the terminal.

```
#ifndef VERSIONS_H
#define VERSIONS_H

#define __SOFTWARE_REVISION__ 100

#endif
```

I am able to extract the `#define` line, but the number.

```
#!perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;
my $line;
my $file = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
        print if /__SOFTWARE_REVISION__/;
}
close ($fh);
```

Comment: That'll also print out every line that uses the macro. You need to include the `#define` part in your regular expression. Also, look up *capturing groups* and how to match a number.

Comment: You can use `gcc` to get the definitions in a clean format: `gcc -E -dM hdr.h | grep __SOFTWARE_REVISION__`. Unless you have some other reason to use Perl for this problem.

Comment: Following the comment by @rici I'd perhaps recommend to use `gcc` to extract defines. (And then pick out the one you need in Perl. I am assuming that this comes up in a Perl program; I wouldn't choose Perl for just this.)  Added a comment to my answer.

Comment: A particular heinous approach would involve using `h2xs` for it's true purpose of converting C header files to Perl's XS glue. But, don't do that. :)

Answer (score 4):

The regex matches for any line that contains that literal phrase, not only where it is defined.  You need to specify the line far more precisely, and to *capture* the needed number.

The code also proceeds to loop through the file needlessly.

With a few more adjustments

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

my $file = shift @ARGV;
die "Usage: $0 filename\n" if not $file or not -f $file;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^\s*#\s*define\s+__SOFTWARE_REVISION__\s+([0-9]+)/) {
        say "Software revision: $1";
        last;
    }
}
close $fh;
```

If the revision can be other than integer replace `[0-9]+` with a the pattern `[0-9.]+` that allows a period, or `[0-9.a-z]` if (low-case) letters are allowed in versioning ... or simply `\S+`.

I'd suggest to work through the tutorial [perlretut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) with reference [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) on hand.

---

I assume that this need comes up in a Perl program (and not that Perl is the chosen tool for this).

Still, note that there are other, more systemic, ways to retrieve this information using the compiler (see a comment on `gcc` by [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici) for example).

While it is better to use Perl in a Perl script rather than go out to the system, *this* case may be one of exceptions: it may be better to use an external command rather than parse source files, a task well known to be treacherous.

Comment: There could be space after `#` and before `define`, so make it `#\s*`. You could also technically have comments after the `#define`, but it would be really unlikely. I'd prefer to just not specify any anchor for the end of the line.

Comment: @giusti  Good points, thank you; there is no reason for any constraints on what follows `[0-9]+` or `\S+`. Fixed, and added a note

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using regex to capture the version number if present in a line. Note that parenthesis in the regex delimit the capturing group and the variable `$1` is used to access the capture.

```
#!perl -w
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = shift @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    print "$1\n" if /^#define +__SOFTWARE_REVISION__ +(\d+)$/;
}

close $fh;
```

Output:

```
100
```

The regex is more selective than yours, which matches any instance of `__SOFTWARE_REVISION__` in a line. This regex matches `#define` at the beginning of line, followed by one or more spaces, followed by `__SOFTWARE_REVISION__`, followed by one or more spaces, followed by a one or more digit capturing group at the end of the line.

Comment: Is there a need for unix end of line format? I am running windows perl and both ggorlen and zdim examples produce no output. The gcc method might be used with grep regex? No success with it also.

Comment: End up doing: grep "\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)" versions.h | tail -c6

Comment: I'm on Strawberry Perl on Win 10 (This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 1 (v5.26.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread). Is it loading the file working OK (i.e. can you just print)?